# How to load the .yml file into Mongoid.load! inline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, yaml

I'm having odd issues on Heroku with paths. I have a rails subfolder named "scrapes" where I keep a number of Watir scrapes I'd like to schedule.

Is there a way to load the information in the YML (for production I imagine) inline instead of going looking for a file?

Comment: Can you provide some more info on the 'odd issues on Heroku with paths' please, as it might make sense to solve this

Answer (score 1):

In direct answer to your question, you can create the connection yourself. I have no yet tracked down the helper .load! however Mongoid.Client is the class that generates a connection from the yml. It appears that a connection is made for each session with just this:

```
Mongo::Client.new(
       configuration[:hosts],
       options(configuration).merge(database: configuration[:database])
)
```

Where configuration is the session from the yml. This is found in [factory.rb](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/clients/factory.rb) for client.

The Options method being called above is:

```
def options(configuration)
    config = configuration.dup
    options = config.delete(:options) || {}
    options.reject{ |k, v| k == :hosts }.to_hash.symbolize_keys!
end
```

**Alternative:**

You can use the Mongoid configure which accepts a block describing the config.

```
Mongoid.configure do |config|
    config.connect_to("mongoid_test")
end
```